# Bold Tags in HTML/CSS

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, python-3.x

I converted a file from PDF to HTML using an online converter with the goal of extracting bolded features from the HTML document. However, I cannot find any bold tags (HTML or CSS) on the HTML script but when I open the HTML file on a web browser, the bolded characters appear in bold.

Look at this example HTML excerpt for a bolded feature

```
<div class="t m0 x3 h3 y9 ff2 fs0 fc0 sc0 ls11 ws0">1.<span class="ls0"> <span class="_ _1"> </span><span class="ls1">My Laptop</span> </span></div>
```

The above HTML script outputs `**1. My Laptop**`

Here is the HTML excerpt from an unbolded feature

```
<div class="t m0 x3 h4 y15 ff3 fs0 fc0 sc0 ls11 ws0">2<span class="ls0"> <span class="_ _2"> </span><span class="ls8">Laptops <span class="ls4">are</span></span> <span class="ls13">grea</span>t <span class="ls7">tools </span> <span class="lsd">in codi<span class="_ _3"></span>ng with<span class="_ _3"></span> the <span class="ls0">C<span class="ls1f">ommand </span>L</span>ine.  <span class="ls0"> </span></span></span></div>
```

The above script prints  `2. Laptops are great tools in coding with the Command Line`.

As you can see, they both share a lot of similar class tags. Howvever, here are the different tags they have:

```
(h3, h4), (y9, y15), (ff2, ff3)
```

These are the descriptions of the tags I obtained from the heading of the HTML file

```
**h3:** .h3{height:29.275313px;} Looks like a tag for height
**h4:** .h4{height:28.940625px;} Looks like a tag for height

**y9:** .y9{bottom:891.946667pt;} Looks like a tag that measures the vertical position of the character on the HTML page
**y15:** .y15{bottom:655.928000px;} Looks like a tag that measures the vertical position of the character on the HTML page


**ff2:** .ff2{font-family:ff2;line-height:0.904297;font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;visibility:visible;} 
**ff3:** .ff3{font-family:ff3;line-height:0.895996;font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;visibility:visible;}
```

I code primarily in Python so I'm a newbie in HTML and CSS. I searched online for ways to identify bold tags on HTML/CSS files and my research narrowed it down to three ways:

`- **font-weight: bold|bolder**`

As shown above, the tags font-weight shows normal for both bolded and unbolded characters

`- **the <b> Element**`

There are no  HTML tags on the file

`- **the <strong> Element**`

There are no  HTML tags on the file

Is there something else that I'm not looking at? I'm open to solutions across different programming languages (Python, JavaScript etc) and I look forward to answering any more questions you have.

Comment: You've done some good detective work there finding the class names that are different between the two and I think you'll find your answer if you look for the css properties applied to these classes: `_ _1` and `ls1` for bolded text. Find those props and add them here - https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-swartz-pu8us and see if it works.

Comment: Thank you for the kind word and for the response. I just added the css properties for `ls1` to the link and there is no difference. However, my HTML file does not have css properties for  `_ _1`  Is that weird? Also, when I dug further, I discovered that not all bold characters (<20%) have the css property `_ _1`. No unbolded character has the `_ _1` css property

Answer (score 0):

Well some bold letter could be made by CSS through another page like bootstrap.

Well maybe there are some tags are filtered and put a style like in js check what contains the right thing to be bold.

Well it has to do with the converter as well.